# After the redesign the "possible vandalism: deletions" page is virtually useless

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools

I've already put a [question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192417/improvements-to-the-possible-vandalism-deletions-flag) about possible improvements to this page, but since the redesign of Stack Overflow even what information I could get from the page has disappeared.

It used to be that the links to the deleted questions and answers were shown in a slightly different colour. I think that the answers used the "visited link" colour. This meant that I could scan the page and fairly quickly decide what to do with most of the flags. If the user was deleting questions then (given the criteria for being able to delete a question are fairly strict) I would more often than not just mark those as helpful as I could pretty much guarantee that the user was just cleaning up their less than stellar questions.

Then I could concentrate on checking out the others.

Now I can't even do that as question and answers links are presented in the same colour.

Ideally I'd like some of the ideas I presented in the MSE question implemented, but at the very least can we have the different colours back?